# How do I find the value of a ViewBag variable list item in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a case where I am loading a combobox based on a viewbag where it is populated by a select list

So the selectlist is populated via this code

```cs
private SelectList GetBranches(int? selected = null)
{
    IPracticeRepository rep = db.GetPracticeRepository();

    var curPracticeId = GetUser()?.PracticeId ?? 0;
    var branches = rep.GetById(curPracticeId).Branches;
    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (selected == null) selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = true, Text = "", Value = "" });
    foreach (var item in branches)
    {
        if (item.CanCollectReceipts)
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Id.ToString(), Text = item.Name, Selected = selected == item.Id });
    }
    if (selectList.Count == 0) selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = true, Text = "", Value = "" });

    return new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");
}
...

ViewBag.Branches = GetBranches(invoice.Visit.Branch.Id)
```

I then want to set a variable which will hide or show the combo box based on whether the first value is `""` as set when the count is 0.

```cs
if (ViewBag.Branches == "")
{
    setSite = false;
}
else
{
    setSite = true;
}
ViewBag.Setsite = setSite;
```

So obviously the above code is not working but I am trying to figure out how do I find the value of that first value in the viewbag so I can set my variable.

Comment: `if (((SelectList)ViewBag.Branches).First().Value == "")`?

Comment: perfect.  Please add it as an asnwer so I can up tick it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
if (((SelectList)ViewBag.Branches).First().Value == "")
```

Although, if you are still on the controller side, then it's probably cleaner to

```cs
var the_list = GetBranches(invoice.Visit.Branch.Id); // Guarantees at least 1 element in the list

ViewBag.Branches = the_list;
if (the_list.First().Value == "")
{
  ...
}
```

Although still, if you are still on the controller side, you probably don't want to save `setSite` in the bag in the first place, given that it's strictly linked to the contents of the list. So you probably should move that part to the view:

```cs
@{
    bool setSite = (((SelectList)ViewBag.Branches).First().Value != "";
}

// using setSite in the markup
```